# Что значит выражение "через год"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, даты

**"Через год"** ― это через 12 месяцев или через один целый год, на следующий?
Например, сейчас июнь 2017 года. Июнь 2019 года ― по отношению к сегодняшнему моменту ― это "через год" (то есть через следующий, 2018) или "через два года " (т.е. через 24 месяца)?
*Как правильно сказать с точки зрения русского языка?*

Answer (score 2):

Выражение "**через год**" означает *"в следующем году, приблизительно в том же месяце*" (возможно расхождение на 1-2 месяца). Если в 2017 году вы говорите о том же месяце 2019-го, то "**через два года**". Но без дополнительных оговорок это не означает "*через 12 месяцев*" - так можно сказать, но это излишне формально (характерно для сроков, типично измеряемых в месяцах, и для юридически значимых текстов). Если для вас важна точность до месяца, то возможно, например: "**через два года в этом же месяце**" или даже "*ровно через два года*" (это ещё не будет означать, что того же числа, но точность до месяца гарантирует).

Answer (score 2):

У вас значение выражения "спустя год" сомнений не вызывает? "Через год" - это почти то же самое. Год должен пройти. Ровно или примерно год, от одного момента до другого, без учета календарных тонкостей.

> "Через год" ― это через 12 месяцев или через один целый год, на следующий?

Это именно **через 12 месяцев** или **год спустя**. Обычно - не обязательно строго, не день в в день, но примерно. Значение предлога "через" в русском языке с единицами времени означает именно то, когда пройдет указанный срок, начиная от текущего или обозначенного времени.

Через "пять минут" - текущий *момент* + пять минут.
Через "два дня" - когда пройдет 48 часов.
Через "неделю" - в этот же день на следующей неделе.
Через "год" - того же числа на **следующий** год.
Через "два года" - того же числа два года спустя.
Это если строго. Но обычно эти сроки имеются в виду примерные.

То, что вы имели в виду, "через один новый год" - это более редкая форма, она могла бы означать "1 января 2019-го", если идет 2017-й, но скорее всего она потребовала бы какого-то пояснения, что именно автор хотел сказать.

*Ваше же предположение, что "год" может в каком-то сочетании означать два фактических года, просто не имеет формы для своего выражения. Мне понятно, как вы рассуждали, что должен пройти полный календарный год - и только по его прошествии надо искать нужную дату... Но это совершенно неестественно для языка, да и вообще для рассуждений. Так мыслить - это только запутать и себя и собеседника.*