# Через неделю — это когда?

Tags: грамотная-речь, даты

Я занимался у педагога по вокалу каждую неделю по понедельникам, а с сентября занимаюсь в два раза меньше: один понедельник занятие, одно пропускаю и так далее.

И возникла у нас терминологическая путаница, как правильно сказать: следующее занятие будет через неделю или через две недели?

Вот календарик сентября 2018 года:

[image: календарь на сентябрь 2018]

Третьего сентября было занятие. Занятие закончилось, я говорю: "окей, следующий раз *через неделю*, 17 сентября, да?" - и слышу в ответ "да, следующий раз *через две недели*, 17 сентября".

Как сказать правильно в подобной ситуации — через неделю или через две недели?

Читал похожий вопрос про "[через год](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/432747/182097)", но только больше запутал себя.

Comment: Рассуждал так: текущая неделя начинается с 03 сентября, неделя начинающаяся 17 числа - это неделя через одну от текущей (посмотрите на рисунок). То же самое и с другой стороны: пропускаем одну неделю - значит встречаемся через неделю. Логично?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если 3-го числа нужно сослаться на 17-е, то  правильно "через **две** недели".

Этот случай отличается от неформального обозначения *периодичности* проведения занятий "занятия проводятся **через неделю**" (= раз в **две** недели): буквально это означает, что **одна** неделя "пропускается" (на ней нет занятий). При этом, несмотря на упоминание "**одной**" недели, *промежуток* между занятиями равен **двум** неделям, как требуется и в вашем указании на дату следующего занятия.

Comment: То есть третьего числа "встретимся на следующей неделе (10го)" = "встретимся через неделю (10го)", и "встретимся через две недели (17го)".

Comment: Да, именно так. Однако вариант "на следующей неделе" неточен: он  указывает **не** на _число_ месяца, а только на промежуток от ближайшего будущего понедельника до воскресенья). Поэтому (если число не называется явно) лучше "через,,,".

Answer (score 2):

В данном выражении "неделя" означает не календарную неделю (период с понедельника по воскресенье). А означает именно **7 дней** — спустя 7 дней.

Соответствующий пункт из толкового словаря:
Неделя — период времени в семь дней, отчисляемый от какого-либо дня.
*Уехать на две недели.

Зайти за документами **через неделю**.*

То есть — через неделю = через 7 дней = в такой же день следующей недели (понедельник).